# "Osteoarthritis patients" vs "people with osteoarthritis"

Tags: politeness

In the scientific literature, I've seen two different preferences to refer to "people who have disease X". For example:

1. Osteoarthritis patients
2. People with osteoarthritis

What are the actual differences? Why do some authors (strongly) prefer the latter over the former? Is it more respectful to those people?

Comment: Patients [with Parkinson's disease](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&biw=1327&bih=619&tbm=bks&ei=ftTNWsSXGYSbwATX34rwCw&q=%22patients+with+Parkinson%27s%22&oq=%22patients+with+Parkinson%27s%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...19266.26944.0.28100.13.13.0.0.0.0.117.1387.1j12.13.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.sjYOKm17sKk) vs [Parkinson's patient](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Parkinson+patient%22&num=20&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj40obm8rHaAhXDjJAKHVtnD3EQ_AUIECgB&biw=1327&bih=619)

Comment: I don't think there's any difference in meaning or in tone. Perhaps identifying someone by their medical condition could be seen to be insensitive and/or disrespectful.  A bit like saying someone is "an Asperger's" rather than saying they "have" or "suffer" from that particular syndrome or condition.

Comment: If you aren’t undergoing treatment for X you wouldn’t be described as an X patient. For example, say I have a cataract but it isn’t advanced enough for treatment, I’d be a person with cataract but not a cataract patient.

Comment: 'Osteoarthritis patients' sounds more clinical! (Both senses.) I'd expect the more formal term to be used in a medical register, but 'people with osteoarthritis' to be used when actually conversing with or more broadly communicating with such sufferers. People don't like to be defined as 'patients/invalids'; they're still real people.

Comment: The general issue here is one that can be summarized as _identity-first vs. people-first language_. There are a great number of webpages about this issue with strong views on both sides. Here is the first page of a Google search:  https://www.google.de/search?q=identity-first+vs.+people-first&oq=identity-first+vs.+people-first&aqs=chrome..69i57.415j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I agree with @Spagirl and EdwinAshworth, "Osteoarthritis patients" implies that there is some institutional (medical) context. To be a patient, you must at least have a doctor's diagnosis, and you must have received treatment at some point if not currently receiving treatment.

Comment: Whatever you saw in the scientific literature, can you distinguish enough to make sense of it, or not?